# How to create a button with onclick with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates a couple of buttons. The problem is that the onclick attribute is not working. How can I use this attribute in JavaScript?

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var name = results.rows.item(i).name;

        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.className = "buttons";
        button.value = name;
        button.onclick = function() {
            alert("assa");
        };

        var listIt = document.createElement("li");
        listIt.className = "item";
        listIt.appendChild(button);

        var favs = document.getElementById("favs");
        favs.appendChild(listIt);
    }
}
```

Comment: The approach is OK, see https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/DOM/element.onclick Can you create a demo of your problem on jsfiddle?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code. Any JS errors?

Comment: It seems already working fine... Check it out..http://jsfiddle.net/3VXrF/

Comment: Caveats: 1. default button type is `submit` (except in older IE due to bugs), so because you don't `return false` from the event handler, if the button is in a form, the form will be submitted afterwards. Also setting `value` on the button does nothing (except in older IE due to bugs); if you want to add text to the button then append a text node to its content, or otherwise use an `<input type="button">` where value does correctly affect the text. But otherwise yeah... no obvious problem with calling the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing it...is calling addEventListener (in case of Mozilla/webkit browsers) or attachEvent (IE browsers).

```
function createButton(){
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerHTML = 'Click Me';
    if(btn.addEventListener)
        btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
            alert('hello');
        });
    else
        btn.attachEvent('click',function(){ alert('hello'); });
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/L2KD5/

Edit: Check the following link for a more generic implementation: https://gist.github.com/eduardocereto/955642

Comment: Or assign the handler function to the first argument of `createButton`, and use that when adding the handlers instead of writing duplicate code.